# Fade out animation on DockPanel

Tags: wpf, fadeout

```
<DockPanel Name="MyPanel" IsVisibleChanged="MyPanel_IsVisibleChanged">
            <DockPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="IsVisibleChanged"> // error here

                </EventTrigger>
            </DockPanel.Triggers>
 </DockPanel>
```

Above is my dockpanel xmal code. Because IsVisibleChanged is not a RoutedEvent I can not add in the EventTrigger this code:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="hideMe">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" To="0.0"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:5" To="0.75"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

I try to give a fade out animation to my dockpanel.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an event trigger, I would use a normal trigger to check the value of the `Visibility` property of the `DockPanel`.

You can create a style on the DockPanel to do it, like this:

```
<DockPanel Name="MyPanel">
    <DockPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <!-- Set storyboard to run when DockPanel is set visible here: -->

                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <!-- Set storyboard to run when DockPanel is no longer set visible here: -->

                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Style>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thats because when visibility is toggled it just collapses/hides the visual tree. Its annoying and a design fault imho.